# Phoenix: API controller gets error regardless of params

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got a controller that looks like this:

```
defmodule PrefectWeb.DocumentController do
  use PrefectWeb, :controller

  alias Prefect.Queue

  def create(conn, params) do
    case Prefect.add(Queue, struct(Prefect.Document, params[:id])) do
      nil -> conn 
        |> put_status(404) 
        |> render("error.json")
      status -> {:ok, status}
    end
  end
end
```

The create method is supposed to add the `params[:id]` to the `Queue` process. My unit test looks like this:

```
defmodule PrefectWeb.DocumentControllerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  use PrefectWeb.ConnCase

  setup do
    params = [
      env: "test",
      id: 1,
    ]

    [params: params]
  end

  test "creation", %{conn: conn, params: params} do
    conn
    |> post(document_path(conn, :create, params))

    assert json_response(conn, 422)
  end
end
```

This spec returns this error:

```
1) test creation (PrefectWeb.DocumentControllerTest)
   test/prefect_web/controllers/document_controller_test.exs:27
   ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for nil. This protocol is implemented for: Date.Range, File.Stream, Function, GenEvent.Stream, HashDict, HashSet, IO.Stream, List, Map, MapSet, Range, Stream
```

If I change the controller function to his:

```
def create(conn, %{"params" => params}) do
  ...
end
```

I get this error:

```
1) test creation (PrefectWeb.DocumentControllerTest)
     test/prefect_web/controllers/document_controller_test.exs:27
     ** (Phoenix.ActionClauseError) could not find a matching PrefectWeb.DocumentController.create clause
     to process request. This typically happens when there is a
     parameter mismatch but may also happen when any of the other
     action arguments do not match. The request parameters are:

       %{"env" => "test", "id" => "1"}
```

Why can't I pass the `params[:id]` to the create method correctly?

**Update**

Adding request headers doesn't help either:

```
|> put_req_header("content-type", "application/json")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params map is string and not atom based. Try changing your controller to

```
defmodule PrefectWeb.DocumentController do
  use PrefectWeb, :controller

  alias Prefect.Queue

  def create(conn, params) do
    case Prefect.add(Queue, struct(Prefect.Document, params["id"])) do
      nil -> conn 
        |> put_status(404) 
        |> render("error.json")
      status -> {:ok, status}
    end
  end
end
```

and your test to

```
defmodule PrefectWeb.DocumentControllerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  use PrefectWeb.ConnCase

  setup do
    params = %{
      "env" => "test",
      "id" => 1
    }

    [params: params]
  end

  test "creation", %{conn: conn, params: params} do
    conn
    |> post(document_path(conn, :create, params))

    assert json_response(conn, 422)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah! Thank-you. That was more than a little confusing, ha.

Answer (score 0):

You are asserting on the conn created in `setup`, instead of the one returned from `post`. Try re-binding the `conn` before the assert.

```
  test "creation", %{conn: conn, params: params} do
    conn = 
      conn
      |> post(document_path(conn, :create), params)

    assert json_response(conn, 422)
  end
```

Comment: This makes the error `** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for nil.`.

Comment: Ah, good catch, but this takes us to the other error I was originally suffering.